# Creating individual and unique tooltips per click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been using the w3school tooltip code to get a tooltip to appear after something has been clicked. I've managed to get the pop up to appear for every clickable item (in this case it's just some simple text) but the problem is that it always appear in the same spot. Rather than the tooltip appear right above the text that was clicked, it always appear above the first text.

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div><br><br><br>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div> <br><br><br>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div><br><br><br>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div><br><br><br>

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: relative
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}

function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Here's the link to the a jsfiddle with a working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/codingcoder96/qcxshej0/

Comment: Please add the javascript code too. `myFunction() is not defined here.

Comment: `id` property must have a unique value. You have 4 elements with the same `id`.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo ahh you're right! If I have it in a loop so that rather than the id="popup" it would be id="popup{{i}}" where i is in the index in the loop, how would I access that id through css?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code:

1. An element's ID attribute **must be unique** across the whole HTML page. In your code a lot of elements have the same ID.
2. I wouldn't use **onclick=""** - I'd add an **eventListener** in the JS code (it helps decoupling JS from HTML)

```js
// "grabbing" the popups
const popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popup')

// adding a click eventListener to every popup container
popups.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    togglePopup(this)
  })
})

// getting the child of the container
// and toggling show class
function togglePopup(container) {
  // [id^=myPopup] is a traditional CSS selector, that selects
  // all elements whose ID begins with "myPopup"
  // by calling querySelector on the container, we only look
  // for elements that are child nodes of the container
  // so the CSS selector is narrowed down to those elements
  container.querySelector('[id^=myPopup]').classList.toggle('show')
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: relative z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">A Simple Popup! 1</span>
</div><br><br><br>
<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">A Simple Popup! 2</span>
</div><br><br><br>
<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup3">A Simple Popup! 3</span>
</div><br><br><br>
<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup4">A Simple Popup! 4</span>
</div><br><br><br>
```